# jQuery set Blink text before innerHTML declare

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to set blink text on my jQuery code below:

```
for(var i in list)
{
    html += '<td class="box"><span class="Ashar">'+ list[i]+'<div class="timeValue">'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+'</div></span></td>';

    if(jsonStr.currentTime == times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+":00")
    {
        $("#audio").html('<audio style="width: 100%;" class="audioDemo" controls preload="none" controlsList="nodownload"><source src="assets/audio/alarm1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>');
        $(".audioDemo").trigger("play");

        $('.Ashar').blink(); // I want to put it here                       
    }
}
html += '</table>';
document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;
```

If I set `$('.Ashar').blink();` inside loop and before `document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;` it won't work. The blink is not working.

But if I put outside `document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;`

It can work, I can see the blink text.

I believe it's because I put `$('.Ashar').blink();` before `document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;` declare.

Any way how to do this?

UPDATE

Blink function

```
(function($)
        {
            $.fn.blink = function(options) {
                var count = 1;

                var defaults = {
                    delay: 500
                };
                var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

                return this.each(function() {
                    var obj = $(this);
                    setInterval(function() {
                        if ($(obj).css("visibility") == "visible") {
                            $(obj).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(obj).css('visibility', 'visible');
                        }
                    }, options.delay);
                });
            }
        }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed that you put the `blink()` before the html is added to the page, which means the selector doesn't find any elements.

To solve this, you can add the call at the end of the code. As you don't want ALL the elements to blink, only those that fit the condition, you might need to add another class to get around this:

```
for(var i in list)
{
    //Create a var to keep the class.
    var tClass = list[i];



    if(jsonStr.currentTime == times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+":00")
    {
        $("#audio").html('<audio style="width: 100%;" class="audioDemo" controls preload="none" controlsList="nodownload"><source src="assets/audio/alarm1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>');
        $(".audioDemo").trigger("play");

        //Add another class to the var:
        tClass += " blinker";

    }

    //Adapt the html var
    html += '<td class="box"><span class="'+ tClass+'">'+ list[i]+'<div class="timeValue">'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+'</div></span></td>';
}
html += '</table>';
document.getElementById('todayPrayTime').innerHTML = html;

//Only make the ones with the "blinker" class blink.
$('.blinker').blink(); // I want to put it here
```

Which will make the things blink, like you want them to.

Comment: Hi... Yes I knew it. But I want to put it inside for loop function not outside

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Why would you want to put it inside the code? It will only lead to more unnecessary calls.

Comment: because there have an condition, so I need to set it there

Comment: Hi, question.. Can We set the blink will set for 1 minutes, after that clear the blink. Please advice and please see my updated post for blink function

Comment: @HiDayurieDave you should consider creating a separate question for that problem. But yes, you could do it with a `setTimeOut` and `unblink()` call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157884/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-jordumus).